# Displaying yii2 checkboxlist vertically

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have an active form which currently displays checkboxlists horizontally but I would like it to display them vertically. I have set the form layout to vertical but it still displays them horizontally:

This is what I have tried:

```
//generates an array of permissions 
$options = Permission::value_list(
   Permission::findWhere()->select('name')->andWhere(['not', ['name' => $name]])->all(),
        ['name']
    );
```

This is the form

```
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['layout' => 'vertical']); ?>
     <?= $form->field($model, 'item_children')
        ->checkboxList($options)->label(sprintf("Available %s", $assigning))
       ->hint("Which type of authorization item are you creating") ?>
```

What do I need to add: currently they are displayed in this way.

[image]

I would like the displayed vertically.

Comment: why you not using css to do that ?

Comment: great idea ill try that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `separator` option mentioned here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeCheckboxList()-detail

Your call would then look like this for example:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['layout' => 'vertical']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'item_children')
        ->checkboxList($options, ['separator'=>'<br/>'])
        ->label(sprintf("Available %s", $assigning))
        ->hint("Which type of authorization item are you creating") ?>
```

Or whatever you want to use as the separator in your specific case.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

> The label to use Note that this will NOT be encoded.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['layout' => 'vertical']); ?>
         <?= $form->field($model, 'country')
            ->inline(true)
            ->checkboxList($options)->label(sprintf("Available %s", $assigning))
           ->hint("Which type of authorization item are you creating") ?>
```

Comment: still displays them horizontally i would like them verically

Comment: problem is happening with label i am sure for that, you can give css for that

Comment: great idea ill try that